# How to make fetch methods return int values for INTEGER columns instead of strings Python sqlite?

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm tring to use this code to read all temperature values from a sqlite database column, but the output is showing `[(u'29',), (u'29',), (u'29',)]` and I'm only storing the numeric value in the database. I would like the output to be `[29, 29, 29]`

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("growll.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()

print "\nHere's a listing of all the records in the table:\n"
cursor.execute("select lchar from GrowLLDados")

print cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: If that is the output then - *sure* that only numbers are being stored? (As opposed to numeric strings.) SQLite will do some basic type-affinity conversions depending upon column type, but otherwise, what you get is what is in the database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("growll.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()

print "\nHere's a listing of all the records in the table:\n"
cursor.execute("select lchar from GrowLLDados")    

print [int(record[0]) for record in cursor.fetchall()]
```

Comment: Worked Perfectly! thanks Since I'm learning python would you know how I would do the same if I the data was a char like L instead of 29?

Comment: Sure: `print [record[0] for record in cursor.fetchall()]` should work if fetchall() returns `[(u'L',), (u'L',), (u'L',)]` for example. The `u` in front of the strings just mean that they are `unicode` strings, by the way.

Comment: To use this data how I can store it in a new variable because if I trie to read the record varialble there is only the last read variable not the list. Thanks

Comment: To get `[29, 29, 29]` into a variable, assign it to one instead of printing it, i.e. `records = [int(record[0]) for record in cursor.fetchall()]`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes thats it I'll use matplot with this data.

Answer (score 1):

`print [int(i[0]) for i in cursor.fetchall()]`

Let me know how you get on.

Comment: Won't this throw a TypeError? `int()` needs a string, not a tuple

Comment: yes I have: `TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'`